# How to add accents to bibliography title?

Tags: bibliographies, languages, naming

Found out how to change the title of my bibliography (using `.bib` file to generate it). However, I need to add some accents to the letters

```
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\addto{\captionsenglish}{%
  \renewcommand{\refname}{Referências Bibliográficas}
}
```

It shows up Referncias Bibliogrficas... How do I fix this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Try `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`, assuming that you save your `.tex` file in `utf8` encoding. I am wondering however, why you have a Spanish (or Portuguese?) title and use `english` as babel option

Comment: If you want to change the name of the bibliography, it seems you are not writing in English, do you? Did you consider changing the language of `babel` to the one your are writing in?

Comment: And probably `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`. However, I don't understand what you don't use the`portuguese` option of `babel`?

Comment: @Bernard: You're right, it's Portuguese language...

Comment: The OP never came back after asking the questioin and it is too unspecific to be answered properly. I voted to close as unclear.